# Detect undefined keys in FormData / MultipartContent

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` I can't access undefined variables inside `FormData`. I have no idea how detect a undefined. Compare against null does not work for some reason. Any clue?

```
public async static Task<MultipartContent> GetMulipartContent(ApiController controller)
{
    if (!controller.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    if (provider.FormData["someVar"] == null)
        doSomething()
}
```

Comment: What is your form data? if you have `int`s there, you should check for `0`. If you have strings, you can check with `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`.